# Python Twisted documentation

Tags: python, twisted

In Twisted documentation when I open any code of Twisted I notice things like

```
@see: L{IReactorCore<twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorCore>}
@ivar called: A flag which is C{False} until either C{callback} or
    C{errback} is called and afterwards always C{True}.
@type called: C{bool}

Compute the allowed methods on a C{Resource} based on defined render_FOO
methods. Used when raising C{UnsupportedMethod} but C{Resource} does
not define C{allowedMethods} attribute.
```

Could anyone please tell me what does the letters C, L like  C{bool}, L{IReactorCore} means and what does @see, @ivar, @type means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s [Epydoc markup](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-epytext.html#inline-markup):

> `C{...}`: Source code or a Python identifier.

> The inline markup construct `L{text<object>}` is used to create links to the documentation for other Python objects. `text` is the text that should be displayed for the link, and `object` is the name of the Python object that should be linked to. If you wish to use the name of the Python object as the text for the link, you can simply write ``` L{object}`` ```.

The [fields](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-epytext.html#fields) (`@…`) used by Twisted [are listed in its documentation generator](https://github.com/twisted/pydoctor/blob/6a8a8d479d40dd58d4f6a761b0197534eb786533/doc/fieldlist.txt) that depends on Epydoc, pydoctor:

```
@author
@cvar
@ivar
@note
@param (synonym: @arg)
@raise (synonym: @raises)
@return (synonym: @returns)
@rtype (synonym: @returntype)
@see (synonym: @seealso)
@type
@var
```